# Boolean-Valued models on a proper class universe

Tags: set-theory, model-theory, boolean-algebra, forcing

In Jech's *Set Theory* he defines a Boolean-Valued model to consist of a Boolean universe $A$ and two functions of two variables with values a complete Boolean algebra $B$.  The functions are $||x = y||$ and $||x\in y||$.  However, when $A$ is a proper class, we cannot define these two functions as sets.  Thus when defining the boolean valued model $V^B$, we are actually recursively defining $b = ||x\in y||$ as a formula $\phi(b,x,y)$.  But then Jech defines $$||\exists x\psi(x,a_1,\dots,a_n)|| = \sum_{a\in A}||\psi(a,a_1,\dots,a_n)||.$$
By Tarski's undefinability of truth, we shouldn't be able to define this on a proper class $A$. I think that this is because we cannot find a set-like well founded relation to justify the recursion. This leads me to believe that when defining a Boolean-Valued model, the universe $A$ must be a set.  What is actually going on here? My guess is one way to get around this is to define $V^B$ inside $M$.  That way outside of $M$ we know that our universe $M^B$ is a set. He does this in later chapters but never explicitly says this.  Is that what is actually happening?

Comment: Exactly the same issue happens with the usual poset-theoretic approach to forcing. Basically, we have a uniform-in-$n$ way to define the relevant truth notion for $\Sigma_n$ sentences. Note that this is identical to what happens with the usual Tarskian picture: we can define the $\Sigma_n$ theory of the universe for each $n$, but as $n$ increases so does the complexity of the partial truth predicate.

Comment: The class you are taking the sum of is *not* a proper class: it is a subset of $B$, specifically the set of $b\in B$ which are equal to $\|\psi(a,a_1,\dots,a_n)\|$ for some $a\in A$.  (The fact that proper classes are involved *is* an issue for making the definition recursively, as indicated in Noah's comment.  It's not an issue for taking the sum, though.)